# Why does ClassLoader.loadClass ALWAYS throw ClassNotFoundException in android?

Tags: android, classloader

Take a look at:

```
    Context contxt  = createPackageContext("com.exam.provider", CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY); // I know, the package must be (and IS) already installed ;-)

    ClassLoader loader = contxt.getClassLoader();
    loader.loadClass("com.exam.provider.MyGestureOverlayView"); // I'm sure this class DOES exist in "com.exam.provider"
```

But this code always throws `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`. Also **note** that both android applications share the same user id via:

```
    <manifest
        ...
        android:sharedUserId="whatever"
        ...
    >
```

I am completely frustrated. Any idea?

Comment: DOn't you need the CONTEXT_INCLUDE_CODE flag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works fine, for me, if I just add the CONTEXT_INCLUDE_CODE flag in the call to createPackageContext.

Comment: I can't believe that. My only mistake was to type 'spaces' between CONTEXT_INCLUDE_CODE and CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY; like this: "CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY | CONTEXT_INCLUDE_CODE". It is a habit from C++ times ;-). I changed it to "CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY|CONTEXT_INCLUDE_CODE" and it works like a charm. yahoooooooooooooo

Answer (score 0):

Is the error at compile-time or run-time

'ClassNotFoundException' here may be because the package is not found at runtime. {after successful compilation}

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling the app from the device or emulator first solved this problem for me.